# Why does ODBC does not work anymore in R?

Tags: r, odbc

I updated R from MS R Open and R 4.0.1 to R 4.3.1. Since then, I have trouble connecting to DB2 databases via the 'odbc' package (Version 1.3.5). I get the following error (trying to translate from German):

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1135: IM004: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] error with SQLAllocHandle for driver on  SQL_HANDLE_EN

This is the code I am using:

```
connection <- odbc::dbConnect(
    odbc::odbc(), 
    .connection_string = paste0('DRIVER=', "{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}",
        ';UID=', "username", ';PWD=', "yourpw", ';HOSTNAME=', "hostname",
        ';DATABASE=', "db_name", ';PORT=', "port", ';COMMITONEOF=0;'),
    encoding = "latin1"
)
```

However, I am not sure if this is heplful as the code generally works with the old version of R.

The 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER' is installed and the connection via ODBC using other tools works perfectly.

Interestingly, the connection via JDBC works well.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: share your connection code ? obfuscate any personal security related text of course.

Comment: I added my code in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the following at front seems to work:

```
Sys.setenv(DB2CODEPAGE=1208)
```

Problem may be related to encoding issues.